# Pythonで引数として渡すクラスのコンストラクタを書き換える

Tags: python, python3, websocket

Pythonで[simple-websocket-server](https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server)というWebSocketのライブラリを使ってServerがデータを受信したらそれを自分が指定したQueueに格納したいのですがうまくいきません。

このライブラリでは`WebSocket`クラスを継承してハンドラとなるクラスを作り、それを`SimpleWebSocketServer`のコンストラクタの`cls`引数として渡すようになっています。

自分が渡したQueueにデータを格納したいので下記のように関数`f`にqueueを渡し、その返り値の関数がMyWebSocketのインスタンスをreturnするようにしたのですが、うまくいかず、`localhost:4246`にアクセスしても接続が確立されません。

Windows10 1803
Python3.6.5

```
class MyWebSocket(WebSocket):
    def __init__(self, server, sock, address, q): # queueを受け取る(q)
        super().__init__(server, sock, address)
        self.q = q
    def handleMessage(self):
        print(self.data)
        self.q.put_nowait(self.data) #わたってきたデータをqueueに格納

    def handleClose(self):
        print("connection: closed " + self.address)
        self.sendMessage("server exit")
        sys.exit()
def f(l):
    def websocketclasscaller(server, sock, address): # SimpleSSLWebSocketServerはclsの引数が増えていることを知らないので`websocketclasscallerで隠す`
        return MyWebSocket(server, sock, address, l)
    return websocketclasscaller

def main(q):
    p = f(q)
    server = SimpleSSLWebSocketServer("localhost", 4246, p, "../certs/server.crt", "../certs/server.key")
    server.serveforever()
```

SimpleSSLWebSocketServerの継承元であるSimpleWebSocketServerが引数clsをインスタンス化しているところ:

```
   def _constructWebSocket(self, sock, address):
      return self.websocketclass(self, sock, address)
```

[Github上のコード](https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server/blob/34e6def93502943d426fb8bb01c6901341dd4fe6/SimpleWebSocketServer/SimpleWebSocketServer.py#L589:L590)

Comment: インスタンス生成のカリー化やSSL接続など問題が複雑化していて、どこまでできてどこができないのか分からないので、まずは SimpleWebSocketServer に一般的なクラスを与えて動作するか確認してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: SimpleWebSocketServer(SSLなし)で試したところうまくいきました。
どうやら、SSLの問題のようです。